# Which is the better choice – "election counting" or "vote counting"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, terminology

I need the technical term for the counting of votes after an election. I've found "election counting" and "vote counting", which both seem to be used to quite some extent – but which (if any) is the proper technical term?

Comment: In general, I think **vote counting** sounds much more natural.  You are counting *votes*, not *elections*.  Can you provide examples of where you have seen "election counting" used?

Comment: @stangdon I first found it in a dictionary, and then found some support on different sites – for instance "This initiative is commendable as it mitigates against potential election counting fraud." (https://www.ekobagmedia.co.uk/uganda-2021-election-implications-and-lessons/). But you're right; vote counting does seem to be the better choice. Thank you!

Comment: According to the Google Ngram Viewer, vote counting is used considerably more than election counting. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=election+counting%2Cvote+counting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celection%20counting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvote%20counting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Election counting as used there means “counting in the context of an election” it’s subtly different than “vote counting” in this case.

Comment: @stangdon How can I upvote you and give you rep if you put a good answer in the comments? >:)

Comment: Oh boy, again no context and this is apparently the same translation. And in any case, election counting is wrong in terms of counting votes.